# How to get my Live Credentials?

Tags: paypal

I'm using PHP/cURL to make my Paypal transactions. My codes are all done and worked pretty fine on sandbox mode.

***Image of My Sandbox Credentials***
[image]

So i decided switch to Live mode and start the production, just changing the URL **from** 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp' **to** 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp'. After this i got some header errors, i read about and found that i need a **Live Credential** (apparently you need 1 Credential to Test, and another to Live).

I can't find where i get my Live Credentials. Most stackoverflow topics and other tutorials showed and old version of the WebSite that doesn't exist anymore (so isn't working anymore)
**Like This**
[image]

I also tried to **Dashboard>My Apps & Credentials>REST API apps** but they dont seem to give me credentials, because there is no **PWD,USER,SIGNATURE**

[image]

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for your Live PayPal account credential?

Just click on the button "Show" beside API Username, Password and Signature.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
The problem was, i wasn't able to reach this screen.
I had to talk with Paypal's Support, my account was bugged :(